# In windows using python how do I check if the middle mouse button is held down?

Tags: python, windows, mouse, ctypes

I know how to check if the left mouse button and if the right mouse button are held down:

```py
from ctypes import windll

left_click = windll.user32.GetKeyState(0x01)
right_click = windll.user32.GetKeyState(0x02)

print(f'left_click: {left_click}')
print(f'right_click: {right_click}')
```

But what is the code for checking if the middle mouse button is held down?
I'd like to do it with the ctypes function: `windll.user32.GetKeyState()`

I've googled it and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
middle_click = windll.user32.GetKeyState(0x04)
```

You can check the reference here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes